# JavaScript Switch Statement. is the following correct js

Tags: javascript

```
switch(variable/expression) {
    case value1:  
        // body of case 1
        break;

    case value2:  
        // body of case 2
        break;

    case valueN:
        // body of case N
        break;

    default:
        // body of default
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid syntax.

But also note that there's a few more variants:

First of all, you can switch on values as well, one of the most common is `switch(true)`.

```
switch(true) {
  case a === "hello":
    return "first case";
  case a === "byebye":
    return "second case";
  default:
    return "default case";
}
```

Since it will evaluate in order, returning the first one that evalues to true, it will operate the same as the following code:

```
if (a === "hello") {
  return "first case";
} else if (a === "byebye") {
  return "second case";
} else {
  return "default case";
}
```

Javascript also allows no break for leaking into the next case (often discouraged) and not including default cases (often discouraged).

You can also pass object or function references both as the variable being tested and the cases. In this case, switch will compare the references, not the content of the objects (this includes arrays).